# New line counter for new line characters in string literals [Updated]

Tags: c++, regex, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

NOTICE:
This is my same question as earlier, but I simplified it to the required structure. If it is still not looking good, please let me know what is wrong with the formatting for future reference.

I have a project for class where I have to make a lexical analyzer for TIPs. I am having an error in counting the newlines to display on the left side of the screen. Currently, it has a regular expression that increments the line_counter variable whenever \n or \r are used. My problem is that it does not pick up on new line symbols in a string. The program will display it how it is supposed to with the newlines, however it will not increment the counter.

DESIRED OUTPUT:

- As stated in the above paragraph, I need the new line counter to acknowledge newline symbols within string literals.
- I need the last line number to be 20 as shown in the expected output instead of 17 as shown in the actual output below.

WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR:

- Adding additional if statements in the string literal regex for if \n or \r are found in the string then increment the line counter.
- Placing the line counter regular expression in different places in the rules file to make sure it was not being overridden by another regular expression.

ERRORS:
I am not receiving any errors.

The below is a snippet of the relevant regular expressions that I am referencing in this question.
Also, at the bottom of the question are the actual and expected outputs.

**snippet from rules file**

```
 /* STRING LITERAL REGEX */
[']([^'\\]|\\(.|\n))*[']       { if(yyleng <= 80)
                                    {
                                        return TOK_STRINGLIT; 
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        return TOK_UNKNOWN;
                                    }
                                }

 /* REGEX TO COUNT NEW LINES */
[\r\n]         { line_number++; }
```

**Expected output**

```
line: 16, lexeme: |'This string
has
newlines
inside of it'|, length: 43, token: 4003
line: 20, lexeme: |&|, length: 1, token: 6000
ERROR: unknown token
```

**Actual output**

```
line: 16, lexeme: |'This string
has
newlines 
inside of it'|, length: 43, token: 4003
line: 17, lexeme: |&|, length: 1, token: 6000 
ERROR: unknown token
```

**REPRODUCIBLE FILES**

LEXER.H

```
//*****************************************************************************
// CSE 4713 / 6713 Project - List of tokens for TIPS
//*****************************************************************************

#ifndef LEXER_H
#define LEXER_H

// List of token codes

// Keywords
#define TOK_BEGIN    1000
#define TOK_BREAK    1001
#define TOK_CONTINUE 1002
#define TOK_DOWNTO   1003
#define TOK_ELSE     1004
#define TOK_END      1005
#define TOK_FOR      1006
#define TOK_IF       1007
#define TOK_LET      1008
#define TOK_PROGRAM  1009
#define TOK_READ     1010
#define TOK_THEN     1012
#define TOK_TO       1013
#define TOK_VAR      1014
#define TOK_WHILE    1015
#define TOK_WRITE    1016

// Datatype Specifiers
#define TOK_INTEGER  1100
#define TOK_REAL     1101

// Punctuation
#define TOK_SEMICOLON  2000
#define TOK_COLON      2001
#define TOK_OPENPAREN  2002
#define TOK_CLOSEPAREN 2003
#define TOK_OPENBRACE  2004
#define TOK_CLOSEBRACE 2005

// Operators
#define TOK_PLUS        3000
#define TOK_MINUS       3001
#define TOK_MULTIPLY    3002
#define TOK_DIVIDE      3003
#define TOK_ASSIGN      3004
#define TOK_EQUALTO     3005
#define TOK_LESSTHAN    3006
#define TOK_GREATERTHAN 3007
#define TOK_NOTEQUALTO  3008
#define TOK_MOD         3009
#define TOK_NOT         3010
#define TOK_OR          3011
#define TOK_AND         3012

// Useful abstractions
#define TOK_IDENT       4000  // identifier
#define TOK_INTLIT      4001  // integer literal
#define TOK_FLOATLIT    4002  // floating point literal
#define TOK_STRINGLIT   4003  // string literal
#define TOK_EOF         5000  // end of file
#define TOK_EOF_SL      5001  // end of file while parsing a string literal
#define TOK_UNKNOWN     6000  // unknown lexeme

#endif
```

DRIVER.CPP

```
//*****************************************************************************
// CSE 4713 / 6713 Project Part 1 - Lexical Analyzer Driver
// Fall 2020
//*****************************************************************************

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include "lexer.h"


// Instantiate global variables
extern "C"
{
extern FILE *yyin;         // input stream
extern FILE *yyout;        // output stream
extern int   yyleng;       // length of current lexeme
extern char *yytext;       // text of current lexeme
extern int   yylex();      // the generated lexical analyzer

extern int   line_number;  // current line number of the input
}

// Do the analysis
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  int token;   // hold each token code

  // Set the input stream
  if (argc > 1) {
    printf("INFO: Using the file %s for input\n", argv[1]);
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!yyin) {
      printf("   ERROR: input file not found\n");
      return (-1);
    }
  }
  else {
    printf("INFO: Using stdin for input, use EOF to end input\n");
    printf("      Windows EOF is Ctrl+z, Linux EOF is Ctrl+d\n");
    yyin = stdin;
  }

  // Set the output stream
  yyout = stdout;
  
  // Do the lexical parsing
  token = yylex();
  while( token != TOK_EOF ) 
  {
    // What did we find?
    fprintf(yyout, "line: %d, lexeme: |%s|, length: %d, token: %d\n", 
                        line_number, yytext, yyleng, token);
    
    // Is it an error?
    if( token == TOK_UNKNOWN )
      fprintf(yyout,"   ERROR: unknown token\n");
    if( token == TOK_EOF_SL )
      fprintf(yyout,"   ERROR: end of file while in a string literal\n");
    
    // Get the next token
    token = yylex();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

RULES.L

```
/******************************************************************* 
Starting point your rules.l file for TIPS
Name: Stephanie Schisler                NetID: sas880
Course: CSE 4713                        Assignment: Part 1
Programming Environment: WSL C++
Purpose of File: Contains the rules for the project.
*******************************************************************/
%option noyywrap
%{
#include "lexer.h"

// global variable to hold current line number being read
int line_number = 1;

%}

%%

 /* Keywords */ 
BEGIN           { return TOK_BEGIN; }
BREAK           { return TOK_BREAK; }
CONTINUE        { return TOK_CONTINUE; }
DOWNTO          { return TOK_DOWNTO; }
ELSE            { return TOK_ELSE; }
END             { return TOK_END; }
FOR             { return TOK_FOR; }
IF              { return TOK_IF; }
LET             { return TOK_LET; }
PROGRAM         { return TOK_PROGRAM; }
READ            { return TOK_READ; }
THEN            { return TOK_THEN; }
TO              { return TOK_TO; }
VAR             { return TOK_VAR; }
WHILE           { return TOK_WHILE; }
WRITE           { return TOK_WRITE; }

 /* Datatype Specifiers */
INTEGER         { return TOK_INTEGER; }
REAL            { return TOK_REAL; }

 /* Punctuation */
\;           { return TOK_SEMICOLON; }
\:           { return TOK_COLON; }
\(          { return TOK_OPENPAREN; }
\)          { return TOK_CLOSEPAREN; }
\{          { return TOK_OPENBRACE; }
\}          { return TOK_CLOSEBRACE; }

 /* Operators */
\+          { return TOK_PLUS; }
-           { return TOK_MINUS; }
\*          { return TOK_MULTIPLY; }
\/          { return TOK_DIVIDE; }
\:=          { return TOK_ASSIGN; }
\=           { return TOK_EQUALTO; }
\<           { return TOK_LESSTHAN; }
\>           { return TOK_GREATERTHAN; }
\<>          { return TOK_NOTEQUALTO; }
MOD         { return TOK_MOD; }
NOT         { return TOK_NOT; }
OR          { return TOK_OR; }
AND         { return TOK_AND; }

 /* Abstractions */
[A-Z][0-9A-Z]{0,7}           { return TOK_IDENT; }       
[0-9]+                       { return TOK_INTLIT; }      
[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]+             { return TOK_FLOATLIT; }


[']([^'\\]|\\(.|\n))*[']       { if(yyleng <= 80)
                                    {
                                        return TOK_STRINGLIT; 
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        return TOK_UNKNOWN;
                                    }
                                }

"\[[^"\\]|\\(.|\n)]*|'\[[^'\\]|\\(.|\n)]*            { return TOK_EOF_SL; }

 /* Count new lines */
[\r\n]         { line_number++; }

 /* Eat any whitespace */
[\t ]*

 /* Found an unknown character */

.         { return TOK_UNKNOWN; }

 /* Recognize end of file */

<<EOF>>   { return TOK_EOF; }
```

INPUT FILE

```
ABCDEFGH
ABCDEFGHIJ
AB123 123AB A123ZZ  SUM  IFFINESS
AB_123
ab_123
123 
3219012894910
12.132 
.123
0.132
-123 -12.324
%%%%%%%
^
'This is a string'
'This string    has tabs        inside of it.'
'This string
 has 
 newlines
 inside of it'
&
```

CORRECT OUTPUT

```
ABCDEFGH
ABCDEFGHIJ
AB123 123AB A123ZZ  SUM  IFFINESS
AB_123
ab_123
123 
3219012894910
12.132 
.123
0.132
-123 -12.324
%%%%%%%
^
'This is a string'
'This string    has tabs        inside of it.'
'This string
 has 
 newlines
 inside of it'
&
```

MAKEFILE

```
###############################################################################
# CSE 4713 / 6713 Project Part 1 - Lexical Analyzer (flex)
#
# 'make'        build executable file
# 'make clean'  removes all intermediate (lex.yy.c and *.o) and executable files
#
# This makefile purposely avoids macros to make the rules more clear.
# For more information about makefiles:
#      http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/
#      http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html
#      http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html
#
###############################################################################

lex.exe: lex.yy.o driver.o
    g++ -g -o lex.exe lex.yy.o driver.o

driver.o: driver.cpp lexer.h
    g++ -g -o driver.o -c driver.cpp

lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c lexer.h
    gcc -g -o lex.yy.o -c lex.yy.c

lex.yy.c: rules.l lexer.h
    flex -o lex.yy.c rules.l

clean: 
    $(RM) *.o lex.yy.c lex.exe
```

Comment: This question is still unanswerable. We need a [mre] to help you figure out what's wrong with your code. Also, I'm not sure I see how much of an improvement this is over the old post.

Comment: Prefer to fix a weak question over deleting it and then re-asking if for no better reason than you now have two questions counting toward a question ban.

Comment: It sounds like you're just trying to count occurrences of a particular string (in this case newline) in a string or file or whatever. Is that accurate?

Comment: Added the project files link @cigien

Comment: @user4581301 It was closed. I didn't think it would open back up after editing.

Comment: No, you need to post the code as plain text. And questions do get reopened if they are edited correctly.

Comment: A single line break regex is this `\r?\n|\r` not [\r\n].

Comment: @cigien posted the code as text.

Comment: Closing a question is a preventative measure to prevent it being inundated with answers that prove wrong once it is clarified (and prevent people from wasting time on answers that will be of no use). Fix the question and it goes into the re-open review queue. Fix it enough and it'll probably be re-opened. Plus the folks that closed it are probably still stalking around nearby waiting to see what you do with the question. They'll see it's been updated and probably hasten the reopening process.

Comment: All instances of `(.|\n)` should be replaced by this `[\S\s]`

Comment: This can probably be minimized, but it's something we can work with. Voting to reopen. The importance of a minimal question is if you make the question really small while still reproducing the unwanted behaviour, the bug has little room to hide. More often than not, you can spot and squish it without help.

Comment: `\r?\n|\r|$` gets the total number of lines. see https://regex101.com/r/R9IAUW/1

Comment: @user4581301  I'll remember this for next time. Thanks!

Comment: `[']([^'\\]|\\(.|\n))*[']` The quicker version is this `['][^'\\]*(\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*[']` using an unrolled loop

Comment: An fyi. This `"\[[^"\\]|\\(.|\n)]*|'\[[^'\\]|\\(.|\n)]*` is a series of 4 _unrelated_ alternations. Each independent of the other. There is no open-close connectivity, ie `[asdf]` won't be matched with this. In fact 1 of the alternation is a duplicate and it can be reduced to this `"\[[^"\\]|\\(.|\n)]*|'\[[^'\\]`

Comment: Another thing to consider since you're taking into account escape sequences is that you can't tell if something is escaped without first checking if the escape itself is escaped. Lexically you could do it by consuming all the _escape + anything_ when outside of quote processing. Wholeistically, the regex equivalent is `(?<!\\)(\\\\)*` + <character to check>

Comment: @maxt8r: OP is using flex. It's unfortunate that the question is not tagged [tag:flex-lexer] but it's quite clear from the code. None of your suggestions apply to flex analyzers: \S and \s are not valid escape sequences; you cannot use `$` in a single alternative; loop unrolling does not speed anything up because thecl regex is compiled to a linear-time DFA; and regex101 does not understand flex syntax and limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line counter is not being incremented by newline characters inside strings because nothing in your action for the string pattern changes the line counter.

(F)lex lexical analyzers divide the input into tokens, based on the patterns you provide, and for each token the associated action is executed. Patterns are not matched inside other patterns: that would lead to chaos. (`tiffany` does not contain an `if` token, for example. It's a single indivisible identifier.)

The easiest way to get an accurate line count out of a lexical analyser built with flex is to include the option

```
 %option yylineno
```

in your prologue (the part of the flex input file before the first `%%`). Once you do that, flex will do everything for you, and `yylineno` will always contain the line number count. (It contains the line number count at the *end* of the token, which is important: if you want to know which line a multiline token started at, you need to do a (very little) bit more.)

It's possible that you have been told not to use `yylineno`. (Personally, I think assignment restrictions like that are misguided, but I don't always see eye-to-eye with instructors.) If that is the case, you'll need to do what flex would have done for you automatically, which is rescan any token which might contain a newline character to count the number of newlines it contains, if any:

```
[']([^'\\]|\\(.|\n))*[']       { for (const char* p = yytext; *p; ++p) {
                                   if (*p == '\n') ++line_number;
                                 }
                                 /* Rest of the string action */ 
                                 ...
```

You can make your rescan more efficient (also applies to the flex-generated lexical analyser's rescan, since it will add code to do exactly what I did above) by using a start condition to handle the internals of a string literal. For example, you could change that code to:

```
%x STRING_LITERAL
%%
[']                  { yymore(); BEGIN(STRING_LITERAL); }
<STRING_LITERAL>{
  [^'\\\n]+          { yymore(); }
  \\?\r?\n           { ++line_number; yymore(); }
  \\.                { yymore(); }
  [']                { BEGIN(INITIAL); /* Return to the normal scan */
                       /* At this point, yytext and yyleng refer to the
                        * entire token, including the ' marks. So you can
                        * now do exactly what you did in your string literal
                        * action. But see below for some comments.
                        */
                        ...
                      }
}
   /* Other lexical rules continue here */
```

Take a look at the [flex manual section on start conditions](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html) for a longer description of how start conditions work.

Note that all of the actions inside the string token, except the last one which actually accepts the token, contain a call to `yymore()`. [`yymore()`](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Actions.html#index-yymore_0028_0029) is a special (f)lex action which tells the analyser that the token is not yet complete, and that the next pattern will match another part of the current token.

A few side notes on your code:

1. Your end-of-line pattern `[\r\n]` matches *either* `\r` or `\n`. Windows line endings are actually the two-character sequence `\r\n`, so you will end up incrementing `line_number` twice if you encounter one. (However, you are not too likely to encounter one, unless you open the input file in binary mode, because the standard library should remove the `\r` when it reads the line.) The correct pattern to match either a Windows or a Unix line-ending sequence is

   ```
    \r?\n
   ```

   which will match the entire line-ending. You will sometimes see more elaborate patterns, and if your instructor cares about the Museum of Historical Artifacts Never to be Seen Again, they might ask you to cope with conventions that haven't been in use in this century, like the pre-OS-X Apple convention of just using `\r`. My advice is to resist taking that on. Just count the `\n`s, whether or not they were preceded by `\r`. That will be correct on any system you are likely to come across.
2. Your test for excessively long strings is imprecise (I think we've mentioned this fact in another question). First, it counts the quote marks in the length of the string literal, which is probably not correct. Second, it counts escape sequences by the length of the escape sequence itself, rather than the single character the escape sequence is translated into. That will result in counting `a` as a single character, but the semantically equivalent `\x61` as four characters, which is likely to cause perfectly valid less-than-80-character-long literals to be rejected by your lexical scanner. If you use the start-condition solution to counting lines suggested above, you can also correct the computed length of the literal by keeping a separate count of excess characters. (You cannot change `yyleng` inside the token because `yymore()` depends on begin able to maintain it and `yytext`. See the manual link above.)

Comment: Also, I apologise for not seeing this question earlier. You'll probably get better results if you correctly tag questions about the flex scanner generator with the correct tag: [tag:flex-lexer], so that people with flex experience see it. (I already added it here.) Sad to say, many SO residents who jump on questions tagged [tag:regex] know very little about flex and end up creating unnecessary confusion. But if you do use that tag, it's even more important to clearly identify which flavour of regex you care about, because there are significant differences (and lexical analysers are outliers).